# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' widget in database

Tags: flutter, dart

`child: Column( crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [ Text( widget.category, //here )`

I want to display the category where i call it from database but the Text fill occur an error. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `category` as a nullable String. That is of type `String?`. A `Text` widget requires it to be non-nullable, which is of type `String`. There's a couple of solutions:

1. Make the `category` non-nullable. To do that change `String? category` to `String category`. This might give other errors so it might not be possible for you to do.
2. If you are sure it's never `null` at that place in the code write a `!` behind the variable name. Like `Text(widget.category!)`. This will throw errors at runtime in case it is actually `null`.
3. You could also provide a fallback value in case it's null, like `Text(widget.category ?? 'fallback')`. This is probably the safest solution.

Answer (score 0):

This means, category is nullable. So you could write instead `Text(widget.category ?? 'alt text')` what provides some alt text if category is null.

Answer (score 0):

Change `widget.category`
to

```
widget?.category: ""   Prefer this else you'll get null operator on null value error
```

or

```
 widget!.category
```